# using Union query in wpf

Tags: c#, union

I have two views in sql sever and I want to combine both of them by Linq statements
I be grateful if anybody help me to correct my code

```
 string fn = "";
            var hato = (from H in db.vHato where H.HatoFullName == fn select new {H.HatoFullName, H.HatoNo, H.HatoDate}).ToList();
            var hatoList = (from L in db.vHatoList select new { L.HatoListNames, L.HatoNo, L.HatoDate }).ToList();
            var hatoDupNames = hato.ToList().Union(hatoList.ToList());
```

Comment: What is the error you got?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your Union to work you have to ensure objects in both list will be the same.

```
new {H.HatoFullName, H.HatoNo, H.HatoDate}
new { L.HatoListNames, L.HatoNo, L.HatoDate }
```

The properties should have the same name (not the case for the first property) and properties with the same name should have the same type.